# a few days every month usage

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

"A few days every month, he goes cycling."

Is the noun phrase "a few days every month" acting as an adverb to "goes" in the above sentence? There is no preposition before the noun phrase "a few months every year" that may make it an adverbial phrase. So how is the sentence without a preposition in the present form correct grammatically?

Comment: Adverbial phrases can exist without prepositions. What is the question here exactly?

Comment: "Today, he went cycling. Last Wednesday, he walked. The other time, he took the bus. Every time it rains, he brings his umbrella." (I don't see any prepositions there either. )

Comment: To UK ears, I'd say that dropping the prepositions from temporal expressions often jars. It's inconsistent; 'He stayed there fourteen years' sounds fine to me, but 'He's been playing football fifteen years' needs a 'for' (or a final 'now' would possibly make the difference). Here, 'For a few days every month ...' probably sounds marginally better to my ears. Neither should be considered ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

It is an adverbial phrase, just like the ones Brian mentioned, but in some sense it does not modify the verb but the whole sentence "he goes cycling". A clearer example is "Obviously, he ran off.", where "obviously" does not describe the way "he ran off" but rather describes that the fact that "he ran off" was an obvious one.

Also, a prepositional phrase can be used as an adverb but not all adverbial phrases are prepositional. "He runs quickly" has an adverb "quickly".

Comment: No, this is a totally different usage. 'A few days every month' is an adverbial modifying the verb phrase. 'He cycles every other Tuseday' is perhaps a clearer example. Your 'Obviously' is a pragmatic marker, totally divorced semantically from the matrix sentence: 'He ran off. It's obvious!' (I'd add that it's a modal pragmatic marker if I were sure everyone could distinguish between that and a 'modal "verb" '.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Well your distinguishing is based on some theory of linguistics you are using. I don't think it's wrong to call "obviously" in my example as an adverb, whether or not you want to label it as a pragmatic marker. There is a whole spectrum of adverbs. How about "Unsurprisingly, he ran off.", "As was to be expected, he ran off.", "As we expected, he ran off.", "As always, he ran off." and "As he always did, he ran off"? Which of those are pragmatic markers and which are not? Can you give a formal unambiguous definition of pragmatic markers?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Also, you are wrong about the adverbials modifying the verb phrase alone. Consider the following: "Every weekend, she goes to the park while he stays at home."

Comment: Leaving aside terminology, 'A few days every month' has a classical adverbial function, modifying the verb phrase. It is not a comment extra to the matrix sentence; it is part of the matrix sentence. All your other examples _are_ (I'll use the old-fashioned term, which I think inaccurate) sentence adverbials,  though in 'He ran off as he always did' (without the comma) the adverbial must be taken as modifying the verb phrase, an adverbial of manner (with the comma, a pronouncement on the typicality of this behaviour).

Comment: That modifies the two verb phrases. John rowed, and Jill walked, slowly. You need to read up on pragmatic markers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Okay I will read up, but I don't see how it's valid to say that it can modify both simultaneously. How about "Every once in a while, she goes to the park instead while he stays at home."? Clearly the adverbial (or whatever you want to call it) modifies the second part as a whole, not as individual verb phrases. If that is what you mean, I don't see any benefit of considering the adverbial to modify them separately.

Comment: "A few days every month, he goes cycling." : the adverbial says something more about the activity. // "I'd speak frankly with her." : the adverbial says something more about the (advocated) activity. // "Frankly, I'd speak with her." : But here, the 'sentence adverbial' (pragmatic marker; speaker attitude) does not bear upon the activity. It's external to the information presented in the matrix sentence.

Comment: Firstly I want to clarify, in case it wasn't clear, that I don't assume that an adverbial like those we have been discussing must either modify the verb phrase or the whole sentence and cannot do both (in different contexts). But I disagree with your analysis of which it is, in some cases. Consider "As far as she could remember, John did not talk that way."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: And your example "John rowed, and Jill walked, slowly." is totally different from my example, because indeed "slowly" here can modify both (though it is ambiguous and can be taken to only modify "Jill walked"). In your example you can split the sentence up into two separate sentence, however in my example ("Every weekend, she goes to the park while he stays at home.") you cannot because the meaning will completely change.

Comment: This is basic. You're muddling "John rowed, and Jill walked, slowly." with "John rowed, and Jill walked slowly."

Comment: 'As far as she could remember' is obviously giving an external reliability/truth-value comment on the accuracy of the statement in the matrix sentence. It is a parenthetical, not modifying the verb 'talk' (though 'that way' of course does), but giving meta-information. 'Frankly, I'd speak frankly to her' is a well-known example of intercategorial polysemes appearing perhaps too close together. The second is the true adverb (modifying 'talk'), whereas the first, irrespective of whether you call it a 'sentence adverb' or a 'pragmatic marker showing speaker sincerity', does not.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: No I'm not muddling anything. It's possible for a writer to purposely insert a comma into the latter to specify how Jill walked. Why do you insist that there is only one way to take it? As for the other example, I'm just saying that you are putting adverbial phrases into too many categories than I would say are necessary, and it also makes your claims quite untestable because you cannot give statistical analyses to support your understanding. Anyway let's forget it. We both have too different approaches to linguistics.

Comment: Post as a question "In 'A few days every month, he goes cycling,' is ''A few days every month' a sentence adverbial or is it modifying the verb phrase?" and see how many people here share your approach to linguistics.